# Firebase Functions iOS: Response Was Not a Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have built and deployed a firebase function that returns Hello World when called and deployed it to Firebase functions

```
 exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send('{"Message":"Hello fromn Firebase"}');
};
```

However When I call it from iOS through firebase functions it returns an internal error that 'response was not a dictionary'. Passing a value through does not affect it

```
functions.httpsCallable("getCampaign").call {(result, error) in
        if let error = error as? NSError{
            switch FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
            case .internal:
                print("Internal error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print(result)
            default:
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription) \(error.code) \(error.domain)")
            }
        }
```

I assume that this is most likely because iOS is expecting a dictionary to be returned, how can I change this so it allow a string to be returned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two types of Cloud Functions:

- HTTP functions, which are called with `GET` or `POST` HTTP calls from within your Swift code.
- Callable functions, which are calling using the `firebase-functions` SDK in your Swift code.

Your Cloud Functions code is written using the first, while the Swift code is using the second. The two types of Cloud Functions can't be matched.

So you will either have to conver the Cloud Functions to be declared as shown in [writing callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function), or [use a standard HTTP call in your Swift code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory).